# Compilador acusa erro quando tento zerar vetor

Tags: c, c++, array, gcc

Os compiladores acusam erro quando eu tento zerar um vetor com o comando `vetor[10] = {0};`

E ele só acusa erro nessa linha pois também usei ela na atribução `int vetor[10] = {0}` e lá não acusa erro.

O GCC exibe:

> error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
>   vetor[10] = {0};

O G++ dá:

> warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
>      saques[4] = {0};

Comment: Coloque seu código pra gente ver. Só com isto não está dando para entender bem onde está o problema.

Comment: Nota que um array definido com `int vetor[10]` nao tem o elemento `vetor[10]` ... os elementos desse array vao de `vetor[0]` a `vetor[9]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eu fiz este código e testei:

```
int main(void) {
    int vetor[10] = {0};
    vetor[10] = {0}; //há um erro aqui mas compila em C++
    return 0;
}
```

Compilando em C realmente não funciona porque o C não tem [inicializadores estendidos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Initializer_lists). A sintaxe do C permite que esta sintaxe seja usada na declaração mas não pode ser usada em atribuição posterior, por isto explica porque o primeiro que você citou dá problema e o segundo exemplo seu funciona. [Veja no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/YMKWbR).

Já se fizer a mesma coisa usando uma C++ moderno, pelo menos o C++11, este recurso está disponível e pode ser usado. [Veja no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Ra8zgo). Note que a mensagem de erro mostra que deve usar pelo menos C++11.

Entenda que C e C++ são linguagens diferentes. E mesmo diferença de versão da linguagem pode mudar o resultado. Você não pode usar o que não está no padrão, não foi inventado ainda ou não foi implementado no compilador que você está usando. Em C não tem solução a não ser inicializar os elementos do jeito tradicional. Em C++ basta escolher compilar com a versão mais nova disponível no GCC.

A solução de fato só permite **zerar** o *array* na inicialização. Depois você pode alocar números em todos os elementos através de uma laço. Neste caso não precisa ser necessariamente um zero. Outra opção é chamar a função `memset()` que também só permite zerar todos, afinal ela foi feita para trabalhar com *strings* e não números (na verdade a inicialização de todo o *array* é substituída internamente por um `memset()`). Veja exemplos corretos:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    int vetor[10] = {0};
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) printf("%d", vetor[i]);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) vetor[i] = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) printf("%d", vetor[i]);
    memset(vetor, 0, sizeof(vetor));
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) printf("%d", vetor[i]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/QQ0iHo). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/pbyvmlmy-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/Zeroing.c).

Eu melhoro se tiver mais detalhes.

Answer (score 2):

o trecho

```
int vetor[10] = {0};
```

é somente para iniciar a variável

para zerar o array em outra parte do código tu podes usar o memset

```
memset(vetor, 0, sizeof(vetor));
```

Comment: O `memset(vetor, 0, sizeof(vetor)/sizeof(int))` não incializa todos os elementos de `vetor`. Para isso usa `memset(vetor, 0, sizeof(vetor));`.

Comment: http://ideone.com/YYxBwl

Comment: verdade no meu exemplo to pegando o numero de elementos do vetor e nao o tamanho total da memoria

Answer (score 1):

```
int vetor[10] = {0}; // inicializacao
vetor[10] = 0; // atribuicao (vetor[10] nao "existe")
```

A inicializacao e a atribuicao sao operacoes diferentes.

Podes usar `{0}` (ou `{1, 2, 3}`) numa inicializacap; tens que usar um valor *normal* numa atribuicao.

*A minha resposta aplica-se a C. Eu nao sei C++.*